# AWS Federated Access policy condition to specific file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sts

I have a mobile app - server - s3 scenario, where I want to grant mobile users write and read access to a specific bucket.

My Problem with the conditions is that I only came across the option to force the write-operation to have a specific prefix.
Is it also possible to restrict the upload to a specific filename?

I need this because I want to save the url to the uploaded file in a database, and I have no callback that reassures my API about the filename.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!